# What is the difference between "declaring type" and "type"

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have come across this syntax in some declaration files

```
interfaces.d.ts
...
declare type TStringOrNumber = string | number

declare interface IObj {
  name: string
  value: TStringOrNumber 
}
```

I get declaring a variable and adding a type for it, but it doesn't make sense for me to use it for typings.

Is there any reason at all for the `declare` keyword? 
You can still use it the same, export it, extend it etc..

Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.  See [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1940#issuecomment-98874436).

Comment: That's what i thought! Thanks!